# Does eating chocolate make you high?

Tags: nutrition, physiology

[This page](http://www.chocolate.org/), as well as many others, says:

> Like other palatable sweet foods, **consumption of chocolate triggers the release of endorphins**, the body's endogenous opiates. Enhanced endorphin-release reduces the chocolate-eater's sensitivity to pain. Endorphins probably contribute to the warm inner glow induced in susceptible chocoholics. This sensation explains why chocolate gifts are a great way to bring joy to a loved one.

I've experienced runner's high, but nothing like that ever happened to me after eating chocolate (or anything sweet at all).

Is the emphased statement about chocolate true?

Comment: What counts as "high"? I've experienced a "chocolate buzz" from eating too much chocolate (if that phrase can be said to have any meaning at all.) I suspect it is mainly the caffeine and sugar, but I could be wrong. I wouldn't describe the sensation as being "high" though.

Comment: Note that although endorphins are endogenous **opioids** (not *opiates*, which are the alkaloids from poppy seeds), and although they bind to the same receptors, they do not have the same potency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This CNN article quotes several researchers though doesn't actually provide much details of studies: http://www.cnn.com/HEALTH/indepth.food/sweets/chocolate.cravings/index.html

> "We are talking about something much, much, much, much milder than a high," said Piomelli, a researcher at the Neurosciences Institute of San Diego. He reported the work with colleagues in the journal Nature.
>
> But a researcher who studies the brain chemistry of marijuana said chocolate contains such low levels of the ingredients Piomelli identified that he doubts they have any effect.
>
> **Piomelli found that chocolate contains anandamide, which is also produced naturally in the brain and which activates the same target that marijuana does.**
>
> He also found two chocolate ingredients that inhibit the natural breakdown of anandamide, which could lead to heightened levels of anandamide in the brain.

A slightly more scientific description of that research is here: http://www.sciencenews.org/sn_arch/10_12_96/food.htm

I couldn't find a link to the Nature article itself (nor any peer reviewed research from them) so far, but the above-mentioned Nature article is:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8751435:

```
Nature. 1996 Aug 22;382(6593):677-8.
Brain cannabinoids in chocolate.
di Tomaso E, Beltramo M, Piomelli D.
```

**In summary,** Yes, chocolate can produce effects similar to marijuana, but the magnitude is significantly lower which is why OP (or the answerer for that matter) don't notice any effect.